# PyCharm can't find Flask template that exists

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

PyCharm's code editor shows the popup message `Template file 'index.html' not found` when passing `"index.html"` to `render_template`. The template `templates/index.html` exists. Accessing `http://localhost:5000/` renders the template. How do I tell PyCharm that the template exists?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click on your templates directory, go to "Mark Directory as", and select "Template Directory".